# Extension has not been invoked for the current page (see activeTab permission). Chrome pages cannot be captured

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Good day.

I'm facing a problem with implementing a Google extension. For technical reasons, I need to open the extension in a separate window (as the auto-disappearing pop-up breaks the logic). However, a nuance has arisen that it's not possible to capture sound from a separate window, resulting in the following error:

"Error when capturing a tab. Extension has not been invoked for the current page (see activeTab permission). Chrome pages cannot be captured."

I've scrolled through all the answers on similar topics but didn't find or didnt understand a solution. Other extensions, such as Volume Recorder Online, are capable of the functionality I need, but their code is obfuscated, preventing me from understanding the differences and why it works for them but not for me.

I would appreciate any help.
I'm attaching the code below:

Manifest v3:

```
  {
    "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
    
        "name": "AnyTalk",
        "version": "1.0.1",
        "manifest_version": 3,
        "minimum_chrome_version": "114",
        "background": {
            "service_worker": "scripts/window.js"
        },
        "icons": {
            "16": "assets/icon-16.png",
            "32": "assets/icon-32.png",
            "48": "assets/icon-48.png",
            "128": "assets/icon-128.png"
        },
        "action": {
            "default_icon": "assets/icon-128.png",
            "default_title": "AnyTalk"
        },
        "permissions": [
            "tabCapture",
            "downloads",
            "storage",
            "activeTab",
            "system.display",
            "tabs"
        ],
        "host_permissions": [
            "<all_urls>"
        ]
    }
```

window.js (background)
\ Opens extension window and send current tabid in query

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  var tabId = tab.id;
  chrome.windows.create({
      url: '../views/recorder.html?tabId=' + tabId,
      type: 'popup',
      width: 400,
      height: 500
  }); 
});
```

recorder.js

```
let recordingEnabled = false;
let socket = null;
let recorder = null;


function getQueryParam(param) {
    console.log('Executing getQueryParam function');
    var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    return urlParams.get(param);
}
let tabId = parseInt(getQueryParam("tabId"));

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    console.log('DOMContentLoaded event listener triggered');
    var statusCircle = document.getElementById('status-circle');
    
    statusCircle.addEventListener('click', async function() {
        console.log('statusCircle click event listener triggered');
        if (recordingEnabled) {
            console.log('Recording is enabled. Stopping recording...');
            recordingEnabled = false;
            statusCircle.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
            stopRecording();
        } else {
            console.log('Recording is disabled. Starting recording...');
            recordingEnabled = true;
            statusCircle.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            captureTab(tabId);
        }
    });
});
function captureTab(tabId) {
    console.log('Executing captureTab function');

    console.log(typeof(tabId))
    chrome.tabs.update(tabId, { active: true }, function(tab) {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            console.error('Error when updating a tab', chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
            return;
        }
        console.log('Tab updated:', tab);

        var captureOptions = { audio: true, video: false };
        chrome.tabCapture.capture(captureOptions, function(stream) {
            console.log('Tab captured:', stream);
            if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                console.error('Error when capturing a tab ', chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
                return;
            }
```

log results are [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yx1hO.png)

Comment: Also, i read that "chrome.tabCapture.capture requires a user gesture to be invoked. ". But if thats the problem, can you please tell me how exactly i should trigger user action like this?

Comment: Open the popup with `focused: false` and remove chrome.tabs.update.

Comment: Same problem, "recorder.bundle.js:2 Error when capturing a tab  Extension has not been invoked for the current page (see activeTab permission). Chrome pages cannot be captured." :( 

It doesn't have access to the tab, no idea why

Comment: You'll probably have to do it from inside a chrome-extension:// iframe added to the web page that points to recorder.html, which should be also listed in [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/web_accessible_resources/).

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer.
The thing is - if you're trying to capture audio from tab/window, not popup, then you should use chrome.tabCapture.getMediaStreamId with navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia (with chromemediasource "tab). And then it will work!